# PHP index.php including structure

Tags: php

I need help. On my site I use URL parameters to decide which other PHP files to include on the page. My first question is: What should be in index.php and what should be in the included PHP file?

On the Internet I found instructions, suggesting this structure for index.php:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <?php include 'header.php'; ?>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php include 'menu.php'; ?>
        <?php include 'content.php'; /* Including page based on the parameters in the url */ ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

With this structure, how can I change the data in the `<head>` section based on the content in `content.php`? For example, for `index.php?option=article&id_article=1`, I will include `article.php` and show the article with id 1. How, then, can I change the `<title>`, `<meta`>, etc content when `<head>` was written before including the article?

Thanks!

Comment: "On the Internet I found instructions..." -- I suggest you try different Internet instructions.

Comment: Can you use javascript?

Comment: Your question is probably too broad to answer here. Maybe you should look into frameworks like CakePHP, Kohana, Laravel

Comment: Probably the user needs to thoroughly understand these issues before trying either javascript or a framework!

Comment: i would never include files based on url params, that is asking for trouble. Consider the security implications!

Comment: There’s no right or wrong answer. There are millions of approaches to creating a website that uses a single script as a point of entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option that is kind of ugly but will work is instead of having header.php `echo` have it simply set variables like `$title` and `$meta[]`. Also instead of having article.php from echoing return a variable like `$html`. Also in article.php you can then overwrite any of the variables set in header.php. Then you can construct your index.php like so:

```
<?php include 'header.php'; ?>
<?php include 'article.php'; ?>
<html>
<head>
    <?php echo $title ?>
</ head>
<body>
<?php include 'menu.php'; ?>
<?php echo $html ?>
</ body>
</ html>
```

Or you can look into `ob_start()` and `ob_flush()` etc...

Comment: Thanks for your comment.Exactly this solution occurred to me too, but like you said, it will work but is a bit ugly. I did have one more idea: index.php should not contain any html code, but including the whole html file for each page (articles, etc.). Is this a good idea or not?

Comment: You could but that defeats the purpose of setting up a template system.

Answer (score 0):

To be as simple as possible, you could make your header a function, then call the function elsewhere...

Example (untested):

```
function drawHeader($title, $desc = "", $keywords = "", $extra = "") {
  ?>
  <head>
    <title><?php echo $title; ?></title>
    <meta name="description" content="<?php echo $desc; ?>">
    <meta name="keywords" content="<?php echo $keywords; ?>">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="path/to/my.css">
    <?php echo $extra; ?>
  </head>
  <?php
}
```

The goal of the above would be so you could easily and quickly do something like...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<?php drawHeader("Home", "Some description", "Some, keywords, here"); ?>
<body>
  <h1>Hello, world</h1>
  <?php drawFooter(); // maybe a footer of some type? ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Or you could set the variables before calling the included file... and in the included file simply echo those values in the proper places.

There's tons of ways to do this, lots of standards and best practices, frameworks, templating systems, placeholders using output buffering, etc.

Answer (score 0):

first the instructions you found have nothing to learn from

as second to get the content of the file article.php

using the url `index.php?option=article&id_article=1`

you will need to use the `$_GET['id_article']`

Example :

```
$page = $_GET {'id_article'};
if (isset($page)) {
$url = $page.".php";
    if (file_exists($url)) {
        include $url;
    }
```

and you can use database for storing the articles and use the query then using

```
if ($_REQUEST['id_article'] == $page) {
    $querythearticle = mysql_query("select tablename from database_name where id_article='$page'");

}
```